# How should I properly clone github repo in VS?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I cloned boilerplate repo in Visual Studio, and I need to use it to create another app and commit changes to my own repo on my GitHub profile, but in Team Explorer I see the link of original repo, not my repo. What should I do?

UPD:

[image]

Here, instead of based-ghost's repo, I need my profile with different empty repo.
I used stock "Clone repository" function in Visual Studio 2019 Community.

Comment: add some pictures of what you have done

Comment: @iceweasel updated

Comment: can you put a english translated version of that page if possible ?

Comment: @iceweasel sorry. done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not very used to Visual Studio i suggest using git Bash for commit and code-push.

If you need to push your project to Github ,create a  Repository first  and  copy its url and then clone it to your machine by  git clone  This can be done either in git bash or  Visual studio integrated git

Then copy your project contents into that cloned git repository then

```html
git add .
git commit -m "<your message>"
git push origin <branch name>
```

So the code gets pushed to your repo and not someone else's

Comment: Oh, thank you for your answer! I'll try it as soon as possible, but I feel like this is what I needed.